# ошибка при установке Android Dependencies в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я интегрирую в свой проект на юнити Admob sdk. С ним вместе ставится ExternalDependenciesManager,после его установки он запускает Resolving Android Dependencies которое заканчивается этой ошибкой

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not determine wrapper version.
   at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.wrapperVersion(GradleWrapperMain.java:111)
   at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No build receipt resource found.
   at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.wrapperVersion(GradleWrapperMain.java:97)
   ... 1 more
```

Я пробовал удалять и заново ставить пакеты, чистить библиотеки manager и кучу решений из интернета. Ничего не помогает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз уж тут такие добрые люди... в общем нужно включить Gradle о юнити и у вас должна быть версию юнити нже 2020 т.е если у вас 2020+ будет данная ошибка